# How to specify the date field in German format for Pandoc

Tags: html, pandoc, markdown

I want to assign the German date `22. Juni 2017` to the date field of the document in the title block of Pandoc. The following works

```
% Titel
% Autor
% 22. Juni 2017
```

but I like the named specification more than this positional one, and I also need to add a subtitle. So I switched to the [*YAML metadata block*](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc). But now, with the German date after `date:`

```
---
title: 'Titel'
author: 'Autor'
date: '22. Juni 2017'
---
```

Pandoc interprets the day part (`22.`) as an indicator for an ordered list:

```html
<h3 class="date"><ol start="22" style="list-style-type: decimal">
<li>Juni 2017</li>
</ol></h3>
```

I found that inserting a comment (which sometimes help to force a break between document parts) `date: <!-- comment -->22. Juni 2017` doesn't change anything here.

The following hack suppresses the enumeration

```
---
title: 'Titel'
author: 'Autor'
date: \ 22. Juni 2017
---
```

but produces a non-breaking space that slightly disturbs the layout:

```html
<h3 class="date">&nbsp;22. Juni 2017</h3>
```

Maybe I'm trying something completely wrong here?

---

#### Background information<sup>[1]</sup>

Recently I switched from LibreOffice to Pandoc for multi-media publishing. I will at least need to produce HTML and PDF (print) in the future. I'm currently working on getting a stable document (structure) for my Markdown source code that was automatically generated from `*.odt` (via Pandoc). That's why I'm checking HTML output: it's fastest. I suspect that issues in the interpretation of the *YAML metadata block* may affect other output formats as well (including LaTeX).

---

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> I added some background information after the question was put on hold.</sub>

Comment: As your issue concerns only HTML output and does not involve LaTeX your question is probably off-topic here. But the issue looks like a real bug and you should file it on github: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues

Comment: *`looks like a real bug`* -- [filed as #3755](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3755) thanks for leading.

Comment: I tried to show that the question is indirectly TeX related (via Pandoc).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of non-breaking space you could use zero-width space (html: `&#x200b;`):

```
---
title: 'Titel'
author: 'Autor'
date: '&#x200b;22. Juni 2017'
---
```

If you want to compile a PDF from the same source you have to use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX since the html entity will be rendered as the unicode character `U+200B`.

Comment: Up'd. My own fix was to escape the dot (`22\.`), but the question is closed meanwhile (sorry for not responding earlier), so I cannot add another answer. I really like LaTeX, but I currently prefer generating it from Pandoc Markdown. I'd expect that the date would be misinterpreted also for different output formats even LaTeX? But I think that this considerations don't make the question on-topic. So if you incorporate my solution into your answer, I'll probably accept it.

Comment: ..also a non-breaking space after the dot would do the trick..